# If you want to edit an unsalvageable NAA post, please don't use the edit button in the LQP review queue to do so

Tags: discussion, editing, review, low-quality-posts

This is somewhat related to this useful question:
[Should we edit the answer we flag as NAA?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16903/should-we-edit-the-answer-we-flag-as-naa)

The answer said, in part:

> If you're a 2k user, knock yourself out - after all, it's just your own time you're wasting. I edit NAA posts myself, on occasion.

All well and good, I agree with that.

However, I want to draw attention to a context where care needs to be taken when editing NAAs. About a month after I had flagged a clearly and unsalvageably NAA (not-an-answer) post (a reply from the OP to another answer with output from the suggested command to say it did not work), I by chance discovered what I consider to be a problem - someone edited that NAA by clicking the <kbd>edit</kbd> button in the Low Quality Posts review queue, causing the review to be completed and the post to be kicked from the queue, remaining non-deleted. Since I discovered it, I was able to draw attention to it (though I could not flag it again), and [the post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569463/cannot-update-xubuntu-terminated-with-error/572734#572734) has been deleted now, so here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see what happened from the [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/572734/timeline) and [the review itself](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/701288) (unsure whether these are visible to those only with 10k etc, comment if needed and I will add screenshots). It was a [good edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/572734/revisions) though not really necessary, but using the <kbd>edit</kbd> button in the review queue caused the post not to be deleted as it should have been. I should add that when this happens, the flag is automatically marked helpful, so it was only by chance that I found it. It could have happened many times before!

Please only use the <kbd>edit</kbd> button in the low quality posts review queue to **salvage the post**. If you want to fix the formatting or remove profanity or whatever from a post that is *clearly* NAA and *can't* be made into a valid answer by editing, click the link to the right of the post and make your edits there:

[image]

I've now started fixing formatting of NAA posts routinely just to try to stop this happening, but I can't reasonably suggest others do the same, hence making my plea in public here.

Also related: [Please, don't use the edit button in the close queue to correct typos or improve the formatting, you are reviewing to close!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8119/please-dont-use-the-edit-button-in-the-close-queue-to-correct-typos-or-improve)

Comment: In my defense, I didn't mean the review queue edit option, but the normal editing process. The review queue edit option is annoying in that respect (or useful, depending on how edit-intensive you're). :(

Comment: @muru I'm sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that your answer was telling people to use the button. I never thought that when I read your answer and I know that you know exactly how review works. I will try to edit my post so it doesn't seem accusatory

Comment: nah, it's fine - just left comment for anyone else who might misunderstand

Comment: Thank you for posting about this issue. I thought posting about this time to time. Though not very frequent, but consistent!

Comment: fwiw, the links are not visible to non-10kers, except for the link to the review (Though the latter only shows the votes, not the post itself https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPbpv.png).

Comment: [here's a shot of the timeline](http://i.imgur.com/Y1jH62U.png) (I don't want to bump my post by editing!) cc @Dan (thanks!)